# How to change the class of the data extracted from another website

Tags: php, html, css, web-scraping

I have scraped some data from one website into mine using this URL

```
<?php   
    $opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
          "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
    )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $file = file_get_contents('http://www.somewebsite.com/', false, $context);
    $arr = explode('<div class="someclass"', $file);
    $a = strpos($arr[1],'<h1>');
    $b = substr($arr[1],$a);
    $arr2 =  explode('</h1>', $b);
    echo $arr2[0];
?>
```

Does anybody know how can I style this data, it is declared inside some class on that website, and I want to add it into my classes. For example, I have my div and I am trying to add that scraped element into that div, but it doesn't respond when I edit it in my CSS, it only works if I work with the class that it has from that first site, and I can't place it inside my div, when I go to inspect on Chrome, it shows that element outside my div and with it's original class?

Comment: Can you post the HTML that you display in `$arr2[0]`? It looks like you have isolated an `<h1>` element.

Comment: Probably the simplest way would be to (a) strip style definitions in the page, and (b) create your own style definitions for the classes from the page. E.g. **.someclass { your style defs }**.

Comment: I tried to use with with my class, but it doesn't work, it only works when I use it with style from that other website.

Comment: use view source, see where the problems are, try html validations. you clearly have a faulty html structure. Inspector tries to fix it, it's not the exact representation of what your output is.

Try that, and you'll find what's going wrong. CSS is not rocket science if formatted correctly it will just work.